# how to format text in the list box

Tags: asp.net

I have to create a program in ASP.NEt. It requires a textbox, a button and a listbox. When I fill out the textbox and hit the button, a text from the textbox will be added to the listbox with the first letter upper case and the rest is lower case. For example, when I enter "hELLO my friend", it will shows "Hello My Friend". I know the logic how to do it but however I do not know why the button does not work.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server">
        public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
           string s = TextBox1.Text;
            char[] a = s.ToLower().ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                a[i] = i == 0 || a[i - 1] == ' ' ? char.ToUpper(a[i]) : a[i];
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script runat="server">
  void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button1.Click += new EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
    }
            public void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                  ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
               string s = TextBox1.Text;
                char[] a = s.ToLower().ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                {
                    a[i] = i == 0 || a[i - 1] == ' ' ? char.ToUpper(a[i]) : a[i];
                }

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```